# Show that $\{f_{n,m}\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L^2(T)$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $T$ be the triangle with vertices $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(-1,0)$. Let $f_{n,m}(x,y)=(1-|x|)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{2\pi i(\frac{y}{1-|x|}n+xm}$, with $(x,y) \in T$. Show that $\{f_{n,m}\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L^2(T)$.

$\langle f_{n,m},f_{p,q} \rangle = 1$ if $n=p$ and $m=q$, and $=0$ if $n \neq p$ and $m \neq q$.

$\int_0^1 \int_{y+1}^{-y+1} f_{n,m}\bar{f_{p,q}} \,dx \,dy$

Are the limits correct? If so what is the conjugate of $f_{n.m}$?

Comment: Remember, your looking for the _complex_ conjugate.

Comment: So would $\bar{f_{n,m}}=(1-|x|)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-2\pi i(\frac{y}{1-|x|}n+xm)}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{1-|x|} \frac{1}{1-|x|}e^{2\pi i(\frac{y}{1-|x|}(n-u)+x(m-v))}\,dy\,dx \\
= & \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{1-|x|}e^{2\pi i(\frac{y}{1-|x|}(n-u)+x(m-v))} \frac{1-|x|}{2\pi i (n-u)}]_0^{1-|x|} \,dx \\
= & \frac{1}{2\pi i (n-u)} \int_{-1}^1 e^{2\pi i((n-u)+x(m-v))}-e^{2\pi ix(m-v)} \,dx \\
= & \frac{1}{2\pi i (n-u)}(e^{2\pi i((n-u)}-1) \int_{-1}^1 e^{2\pi ix(m-v)}\,dx \\
= & \frac{1}{2\pi i (n-u)}(e^{2\pi i((n-u)}-1) \frac{1}{2\pi i(m-v)} e^{2\pi ix(m-v)}]_{-1}^1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

So when $n \neq m$ nor $u \neq v$, the integral above will equal 0. However when $n=m$ and $u=v$, the integral above will equal 1. Hence the set is orthonormal.